# How to solve overlap last value in lable in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to update a new value in UILable but there is overlap last value in that label.

I call API every 30 seconds and get the value for this label every 30 seconds so I need to update the value in this label. but sometimes I face this problem.

[image]

Please draw me a solution for this.

Debugger image
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code which you are trying ?

Comment: How are you updating the label ?  is that a cell ? or view over view ? explain more and add code

Comment: I call API every 30 seconds and get the value for this label every 30 seconds so I need to update the value in this label. but sometimes I face this problem.

Comment: i set this -> self.label.text = "\(intNumber)"

Comment: I think your problem maybe not lay on the Label. As far as I know, in such a situation, you may first monitor the view hierarchy with Xcode debugger to make sure that you didn't make overlapped labels first. Wish this could help.

Comment: You are probably adding a label every time you set the text. Show the code that you have. Not just the line where you set the label text.

Comment: It seems that there are multiple labels in the view Hierarchy. You are probably adding a label when you get the APi Response

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan no there is only One label brother see debugger image

Comment: can you post your ib file on to a public repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Removed UIlabel and set UIButton over UILable

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
self.label.text = "" // Probably unnecessary
self.label.text = "1337"
self.label.setNeedsLayout()
```

Every time you update it from your API.

*EDIT: You probably/shouldn't even need to clear it before.*

Comment: can you explain more about setNeedsLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Core Animation Display Link Layer( CADisplayLinkLayer). You can check out Brian Voong's CADisplayLayer [tutorial](https://youtu.be/b3kZH1vfG2U).

Pass you Label in setupDisplayLayer

```
        var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
        var startValue: Double = 900
        let endValue: Double = 1000
        let animationDuration: Double = 3.5
        let animationStartDate = Date()

        func setupDisplayLayer(lable: UILabel) {
            view.addSubview(countingLabel)
            countingLabel.frame = view.frame

            // create my CADisplayLink here
            displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleUpdate))
            displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        }

        @objc func handleUpdate() {
            let now = Date()
            let elapsedTime = now.timeIntervalSince(animationStartDate)

            if elapsedTime > animationDuration {
                self.countingLabel.text = "\(endValue)"
                displayLink?.invalidate()
                displayLink = nil
            } else {
                let percentage = elapsedTime / animationDuration
                let value = startValue + percentage * (endValue - startValue)
                self.countingLabel.text = "\(value)"
            }
        }
```